# How to plot a 3D plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have three parameters `x`,`y` and `t`. But the problem is my file structure.

My files are named as:

```
e_x_y.txt
t_x_y.txt
```

where `e_x_y.txt` has the error for particular values of `x` and `y` and `t_x_y.txt` has corresponding time values.

**I need to plot the values in `e_x_y.txt` on a `x vs y vs t` graph.**

What is the best way to do that?

I know what x and y values are, so I don't have to deduct them from the file names.

---

To make things more clear,

suppose my files are:

```
e_4_5.txt
45
54
t_4_5.txt
2.0
6.0

e_7_8.txt
32
98
121
t_7_8.txt
2
9
1.0
```

I want to plot the following points:

```
(4,5,2.0) = 45
(4,5,6.0) = 54
(7,8,2.0) = 32 
(7,8,9.0) = 98
(7,8,1.0) = 121
```

Comment: Some clarification: What do these variables represent? Are you measuring the position of something (with an error estimate) at different times? Or can `x`, `y`, and `t` be represented by a function of 2 variables, like `y = f(x,t)`?

Comment: actually I am using a algorithm at different configurations of my neural network. `e` is the error and `t` values are the corresponding times taken.

Comment: Are these 3D points densely distributed or is it only for a few values?

Comment: these are some discontinuous points like in the example. Just that I have hundreds of pairs of files like these. These are values from an actual file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of plot you are trying to make may be difficult to visualize well. I can give you two suggestions: one is what you *want*, and one is what you should probably do instead...

### Plotting 4-D data:

In order to do this, you will have to plot a series of `x,y,t` points and somehow represent the error value `e` at each point. You could do this by changing the color or size of the point. In this example, I'll plot a sphere at each point with a diameter that varies based on the error (a diameter of 1 equates to the maximum expected error). The color represents the time. I'll be using the sample data you added to the question (formatted as a **5-by-4** matrix with the columns containing the `x`, `y`, `t`, and `e` data):

```
data = [4 5 2 45; 4 5 6 54; 7 8 2 32; 7 8 9 98; 7 8 1 121];
[x, y, z] = sphere;  % Coordinate data for sphere
MAX_ERROR = 121;     % Maximum expected error
for i = 1:size(data, 1)
  c = 0.5*data(i, 4)/MAX_ERROR;  % Scale factor for sphere
  X = x.*c+data(i, 1);           % New X coordinates for sphere
  Y = y.*c+data(i, 2);           % New Y coordinates for sphere
  Z = z.*c+data(i, 3);           % New Z coordinates for sphere
  surface(X, Y, Z, 'EdgeColor', 'none');  % Plot sphere
  hold on
end
grid on
axis equal
view(-27, 16);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('t');
```

And here's what it would look like:

[image]

**The problem:** Although the plot looks kind of interesting, it's not very intuitive. Also, plotting lots of points in this way will get cluttered and it will be hard to see them all well.

### More intuitive 3-D plot:

It may be better to instead make a 3-D plot of the data, since it may be easier to interpret. Here, the x-axis represents the iteration number and the y-axis represents each individual network:

```
plot3(1:2, [1 1], [2 45; 6 54]);           % Plot data for network 4-5
hold on
plot3(1:3, [2 2 2], [2 32; 9 98; 1 121]);  % Plot data for network 7-8
xlabel('iteration number');
set(gca, 'YTick', [1 2], 'YTickLabel', {'network 4-5', 'network 7-8'})
grid on
legend('time', 'error')
view(-18, 30)
```

This produces a much clearer plot:

[image]

Comment: `peaks` is a built-in MATLAB function that is often used as a sample function of 2 variables in MATLAB demos.

Comment: so, as I have different values of `x` and `y`, how should I define the `X`,`Y` and `Z` arrays?

Comment: I think I'll need to know a little more about what your data specifically is and how it's generated to answer that.

Comment: @gnovice I have added the details in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I am not convinced this the best way to visualize the data, here's a simple way to do it as you asked. You can plot the 3D points in a simple scatter plot, and map the size OR the color to the values of the fourth dimension `error`. Something like:

```
x = randi(20, [10 1]);
y = randi(20, [10 1]);
t = randi(10, [10 1]);
e = randi(200, [10 1]);

% map `e` to color
figure(1)
scatter3(x, y, t, 200, e, 'filled')
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('t')
colormap(hot), colorbar

% map `e` to size
figure(2)
scatter3(x, y, t, e, 'filled')
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('t')
```

[image: color]
[image: size]

Comment: @Amro I have added an example to the question. Please have a look.
I am not sure what you mean by: `you have two values across a time axis`

Comment: It seems I misunderstood how the data looks like!

Comment: From your comments above, `e` and `t` are values measured for each network configuration `(x,y)`, ie: `e = f(x,y)` and `t = g(x,y)`. Therefore it makes no sense to plot t against (x,y) and e. Rather IMO you should have two plots for each function

Comment: @Amro, `e` and `t` are the values of `error` and `time` for different iterations on the SAME network. Therefore it does make sense to plot them that way. In the above example, first couple of files, for `network 4-5`, first iteration took `2 seconds` and the error was `45` while the second iteration on the SAME network took `6 seconds` and the error was `54`.

Comment: What I meant is that it make no sense to plot `error` as if it were a function of three variables `(x,y,time)` because it doesn't depend on `time` only `(x,y)`. `time` is simply another function of the same input `(x,y)`

Comment: yeah, actually. But, how do I plot it if I need to?