# matlab: how to use an array for coloring a plot

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, points

I have a set of 3d coordinates in 3 arrays `X`, `Y`, `Z`, and the temperature `T` at each point. I want to plot the points as a point cloud, such that each point will have a color according to it's temperature. Something similar to how you can specify colors in `trisurf`. How do I do that?

Comment: the answers to a similar question should give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809881/how-to-plot-a-3d-plot-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SCATTER3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) for that:

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,12,T);
```